# How to cancel activity that is invoked asynchronously from the Workflow?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

We want to invoke a long-running activity asynchronously and after sometime based on the external signal, would like to cancel that long-running activity.

```
Async.procedure(activities::longRunningActivity)
// Execute some synchronous activities
Workflow.await(() -> !messageQueue.isEmpty());
if (messageQueue.remove(0) == "something") {
    // Cancel longRunningActivity
}
```

Currently the only way for an activity to learn about cancellation is through heartbeating. Make sure that your activity heartbeats and doesn't swallow the exception the heartbeat method throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CancellationScope](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal-java-sdk/blob/67c252100daf91c4e65730dac686eaaad4adc9c9/src/main/java/io/temporal/workflow/Workflow.java#L580):

```
  CancellationScope longRunningCancellationScope =
          Workflow.newCancellationScope(
                  () -> Async.procedure(activities::longRunningActivity));
  longRunningCancellationScope.run();
  // Execute some synchronous activities
  Workflow.await(() -> !messageQueue.isEmpty());
  if (messageQueue.remove(0) == "something") {
      longRunningCancellationScope.cancel();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim. I'm using cadence-java client and I've tried CancellationScope.cancel(). Still, the activity is running and in the candence web-UI status is shown as CANCEL_REQUESTED and in fact it is running after the workflow execution is completed. Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Currently the only way for an activity to learn about cancellation is through heartbeating. Make sure that your activity heartbeats and doesn't swallow the exception the heartbeat method throws.